# Not getting passport stamped in Sweden

Tags: schengen, customs-and-immigration, passports, sweden, passport-stamps

I just arrived to Sweden and did not get my passport stamped. However, it got stamped in Germany (I flew to Sweden through Germany)

Is this normal?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes. Since Germany and Sweden are both in the Schengen area, you are not going through immigration at all when travelling from Germany to Sweden.