# Where does my passport get entry stamp?

Tags: schengen, passports, zrh, passport-stamps, muc

Consider this journey JFK->MUC->ZRH (MUC is just a flight connection). When does the passenger actually enter the Schengen zone? Munich or Zürich?

Comment: If you don't leave airport in München you'll get entry stamp in Zürich.

Comment: @akuzma What if in Munich I get into the city and come back to the airport and fly to Zürich?

Comment: Then you'll enter the Schengen zone in München.

Comment: @akuzma I am never done this in Munich specifically but I think that that's not true, the entry in Schengen will be in Munich in any case.

Comment: @Annoyed Last year my friend fight from Kiev stopping in Warsaw and then to Paris, he got enter stamp in Paris. Were regulations changed?

Comment: See also http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/12765/is-1-hours-enough-for-a-transit-at-munich-airport and http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17385/is-a-schengen-visa-transit-visa-required-for-transit-flight-from-vienna-to-frank

Comment: The regulations did not change in this respect, maybe there is a problem with airport facilities. Strangely, the airport website suggests that it depends on whether your plane is docked at a jetbridge or not… http://www.lotnisko-chopina.pl/en/passenger/passenger-check-in/Transfer-passengers/transfer-non-schengen-2013-schengen-ns-s

Comment: Another question about the same topic: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/19785/not-getting-passport-stamped-in-sweden?rq=1

Comment: @akuzma The regulations in that case changed when Poland joined Schengen.

Comment: @Karlson But that was in 2008, I think…

Comment: @Annoyed Exactly.

Comment: @Annoyed Propably I missunderstood him, I have to ask him about that.

Answer (score 10):

You should enter the Schengen area and get an entry stamp in Munich. I never had the occasion to connect in Munich but Schengen flights typically depart from another area in the airport and are not subject to any systematic passport checks on arrival, hence the need for a border check in the first airport in the Schengen area. That's also why [“transit privileges” do not apply](http://www.germany.info/Vertretung/usa/en/05__Legal/02__Directory__Services/01__Visa/__Transit__Visa.html) when transiting through two airports in the Schengen area.